# Determining which home appliances are plugged in based on their power consumption behavior

Tags: power, signal-processing, appliances, home-installation

I placed a current sensor on the main power line going into my household  and I am trying to use that data to determine if an appliance is plugged in such as a fridge or heater. It should be easy since a resistor would draw current differently than a electric motor. Due to the fact that all the currents are added up, I cannot do it. The only thing I can detect is if a fridge or a heater is on from the huge inrush current they draw at startup.  Unfortunately they are all at the same frequencies.

Any idea on how this could work would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen at least two startups try this [ecoisme](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ecoisme-intelligent-energy-monitoring-system#/) and then there is [sense](https://sense.com/). Both install at your electrical panel.  Ecoisme claims to use spectral analysis,  so basically looking at the noise profile that various devices cause on the line.  I have no idea how well it works but one could imagine taking lots of data when a device is running and when it isn't and training a neural network to give you a probability for what kind of device is running.  It seems like the kind of thing that would suffer from a lot of corner cases that didn't work well.

In your case maybe you could try collecting a lot of data and trying to train something to detect the difference.  Not a simple answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You will only be able to determine the power consumption of individual appliances by measuring each appliance individually.

Measuring the current at the AC input to your home can only tell you the total power consumption of your home - you can't distinguish the power consumed by individual appliances there.